Configure properly irqbalance to improve the network traffic
I have a debian 12 machine that gets a lot of softirqs
by calling cat /proc/softirqs
NET_RX on CPU1 is huge compared to CPU0
I would like to assign the irqs on both cores by using the switch on affinity provided by irqbalance.
But it seems my configuration is off because when I do run irqbalance daemon both by init.d but also by testing it via irqbalance --debug it doesn't do anything.
By using ENABLED="1" nothing changes too.
Do irqbalance works also on softirqs? By running irqbalance in screen and checking on htop the CPU0 is never used.
ksoftirqd/1 process still uses a lot of cpu while ksoftirqd/0 doesn't.
Maybe the irqbalance is not designed for softirqs? but on the Oracle website it says that also softirqs are handled.
Could it be that ksoftirqd are directly 2 spawned process that are bound specifically on a single cpu so that ksoftirqd/1 doesn't go on CPU0 ?

if you run the debug irqbalance -d --oneshot, do you see anything after Isolated CPUs? Or check for anything in /sys/devices/system/cpu/isolated or /sys/devices/system/cpu/nohz_full that could be preventing any balancing. The issue in this article isn't the same, but the troubleshooting steps should help, like checking /proc/irq/$i/smp_affinity_list:  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/677073

@Cpt.Whale I found that the irq that is making mess is the usb3 related one, basically xhci_hcd in my case is interrupt 120, because I'm using 2 network adapters via usb3 for transmitting and receiving data at same time and the hardware isn't great a celeron N3000 if I do cat smp_affinity_list it says 0-1 for what concerns the /sys.../isolated and nohz_full they are both empty, well nohz_full says (null) but is the same. The irqbalance -d --oneshot says "Prevent irq assignment to these isolated CPUs: 00000000"
